# oracle compare a date with the current date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to convert a column to a date and then compare the month of the column with the current month.

The column looks like this :

```
Date
0117
0217
0317
..
```

I know how to convert it but cant compare it.

```
select  date,to_date(date, 'mmyy')
from table
where ????
```

any ideas?

Comment: What is the date supposed to represent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the value to a date using `to_date()`:

```
select to_date(mmyy, 'MMYY')
from t;
```

Note that I renamed the column `mmyy` to clarify what it contains.

This returns the first day of the month.

The result of `to_date()` can then be compared to the current date.  For instance, to match the first of date of the month:

```
where to_date(mmyy, 'MMYY') = trunc(sysdate)
```

If you want to match everything in the month, just use an appropriate comparison:

```
where to_char(to_date(mmyy, 'MMYY'), 'YYYY-MM') = to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM')
```

or, more simply:

```
 where mmyy = to_char(sysdate, 'MMYY')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I just want to compare the month so that all records are displayed from a month.

Comment: `trunc(sysdate)` will truncate to the start of the day not the start of the month so comparing on that would only work if you run the query on the first day of the month.

Comment: @MT0 . . . The first of the month is because the conversion to `to_date()` makes the date the first of the month.

Comment: `where to_date(mmyy, 'MMYY') = trunc(sysdate)` will not match any rows unless the query is run on the first day of the month as the default for `TRUNC` is `TRUNC( datevalue, 'DD' )` and will truncate to the start of the day **NOT** the start of the month.

Comment: @MT0 . . . I'm not sure what part of the answer you do not follow.  That code is introduced with:  "For instance, to match the first of date of the month:".  Do yo understand what that means?  The downvote is very rude.

Comment: You are not comparing it with the start of the current month - you are comparing it with the current day at midnight. Try it - `SELECT * FROM DUAL WHERE TO_DATE( '1217', 'MMYY' ) = TRUNC( SYSDATE )` and you will see that it does not return any rows (unless today happens to be the first day of the month).

Comment: See the [Oracle `TRUNC` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions201.htm) - "If you omit `fmt`, then date is truncated to the nearest day."

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the current date to a string and use string comparisons (which would allow you to use an index on your column):

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  your_date_column = TO_CHAR( SYSDATE, 'MMYY' )
```

or you can convert the column to a date and compare it (which would not use an index on your column but could use a function-based index, if you created one):

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  TO_DATE( your_date_column, 'MMYY' ) = TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' )
```

Comment: is there any way to get the month  as a int? for example 12 for the current date

Comment: @on55 `EXTRACT( MONTH FROM SYSDATE )`